# HTML5/CSS3: Como fixar um item de lista não ordenado no fim de todos os itens

Tags: html5, css3

```css
/*   Nav retratil  */
/*=================*/
#something,
nav ul li, inputr,
nav ul input:checked ~li label.abrir {
    display:none;
}

nav ul input:checked ~li,
nav ul li.fixo, li.abrir {
    display: block;
}

nav ul li label {
    color: red;
    font-weight: 900;
    margin-left: 110px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
nav ul li label.abrir {
    align:right;
    cursor: copy;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<nav>
<ul>
<input type="checkbox" id="something">
<li class="fixo">
   <a class="textoimpressao" href="#textoimpressao"> Texto para impressão </a>
</li>
<li class="fixo">#1</li>
<li class="fixo">#2</li>
<li>#3</li>
<li>#4</li>
<li>#5</li>
<li>#6</li>
<li>#7</li>
<li>#8</li>
<li class="fixo">
   <label for="something" class="abrir"> Ver mais &#8609; </label>
</li>
<li> 
   <label for="something"> Ocultar &#8607; </label>
</li>
<li>#9</li>
<li>#10</li>
<li>#11</li>
<li>#12</li>
</ul>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

No trecho 

Ocultar ↟

 como deixo fixo no final somente na renderização do HTML, utilizando apenas HTML5/CSS3?

Comment: Não entendi direito, vc quer que o "Ocultar" seja sempre o último item é isso? Não ficou muito claro...

Comment: @hugocsl, não. Quero que este item cujo texto é "ocultar", sempre esteja no final da lista. Seja sempre o ultimo elemento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se eu entendi bem tem uma forma de muda a ordem sim somente com CSS, primeiro vc tem que definir a `UL` como `display:flex` e direção em `column`, depois disso vc define uma classe para esse item que deve sempre estar por último, e coloca o atributo CSS `oreder:2;` nele.

> `Flex` items have a default `order` value of 0, therefore items with an integer value greater than 0 will be displayed after any items that have not been given an explicit `order` value.

PORTUGUÊS *"Os itens `flex` têm um valor de `order` padrão de 0, portanto, os itens com um valor inteiro maior que 0 serão exibidos após qualquer item que não tenha recebido um valor de `order` explícito."*

Todo item dentro de um *container flex* tem por definição `order:0`, então ao colocar "manualmente" `oreder:2` nele ele sempre será o item com maior *valor index*, e sempre será o último da lista.

Aqui tem uma documentação da Mozilla mais detalhada de como funciona o `order` dos `flex-items` https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/ordenacao_dos_itens_flex

Veja o resultado:

```css
/* Nav retratil */
/*=================*/
#something,
nav ul li,
input,
nav ul input:checked ~ li label.abrir {
    display:none;
}

nav ul input:checked ~ li,
nav ul li.fixo,
li.abrir {
    display: block;
}

nav ul li label {
    color: red;
    font-weight: 900;
    margin-left: 110px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
nav ul li label.abrir {
    text-align:right;
    cursor: copy;
}

ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.last {
    order: 2;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <input type="checkbox" id="something">
        <li class="fixo">
            <a class="textoimpressao" href="#textoimpressao"> Texto para impressão </a>
        </li>
        <li class="fixo">#1</li>
        <li class="fixo">#2</li>
        <li>#3</li>
        <li>#4</li>
        <li>#5</li>
        <li>#6</li>
        <li>#7</li>
        <li>#8</li>
        <li class="fixo">
            <label for="something" class="abrir"> Ver mais &#8609; </label>
        </li>
        <li class="last">
            <label for="something"> Ocultar &#8607; </label>
        </li>
        <li>#9</li>
        <li>#10</li>
        <li>#11</li>
        <li>#12</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: :D valeu @hugocsl, é exatamente isto que preciso!

Comment: @britodfbr legal jovem! Essa solução pode quebrar seu galho em outras situações, pois ela não altera a ordem dos elementos no HTML, apenas na página quando é renderizada :D boa sorte ai!

Comment: :D ;)
Valeu!!!!!!